# So Many Python3 Package Installed in My Linux(WSL - Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I don't have many experience in using Linux so I decided to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux.
I find out that I have many package installed in WSL but I didn't installed it. Is this OK?
[python package listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw9Qc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly normal. As you can see by the `python3-` prefix, all of them come with a standard python3 installation.

For example: `python3-pip` is used to install other packages and `python3-requests` is used to make requests to web pages and API endpoints.

I don't see any problems with this list of packages, it looks fine.

Depending on your distro (for example, Ubuntu), Python 3 comes installed by default.

Comment: Thanks You So Much <3